# chart js flexbox width ignored

Tags: css, vue.js, chart.js, vue-component, bulma

I'm using `Bulma v0.6.2` CSS framework with `vue-chartjs 3.2.1`, trying to put a Line chart inside a Box container. My `chartjs` options are all correct and as advised for achieving responsiveness:

```
responsive: true,
maintainAspectRatio: false
```

I also use a container for my chart as advised (the `chart-container` **class** property):

```
<UserActivity
v-bind:chart-data="datacollection"
v-bind:options="graphOptions"
class="chart-container"
/>
```

with the following `chart-container` CSS:

```
.chart-container {
    position: relative;
    height: 40px;
}
```

but it seems like the chart ignores the parent element's width:

[image]

I looked around and found some hints that the issue may be related to Bulma and Flexbox. Did anyone encounter this issue?

**EDIT:**
This jsfiddle reproduces the issue.
https://jsfiddle.net/c6tu3qgx/

Comment: Can you create an MCVE to show us what went wrong? We can't possible debug based on a screenshot.

Comment: @Terry sure, edited the original post

Comment: This is actually an infinity loop you are entering: flex layout depends on the defined size of the chart, and the chart size depends on the space allocated to it by the flex layout. Either way, you will need to give a specific size to your chart, or turn the responsive feature off.

Comment: @Terry, thank you for your help. Is there any way around, getting the chart fit inside the box (using all the available remaining width) without specifying a pre-defined width?

Comment: Yes. Refer to my previous comment :)

Comment: @Terry maybe I don't get it (I'm far from being a frontend expert), but won't both options (turning off the responsive feature and specifying a size) will result in losing responsiveness? Can you edit my jsfiddle to demonstrate?

Comment: Either options should work. Of course if you use both you’ll be stuck with a static layout.

Comment: @Terry, here (https://jsfiddle.net/fmap029u/) the responsive feature is turned off, still not bound to the box

Comment: You're nesting the entire box in a class called `.column.is-3`, which restricts the width to `25%`. There is simply no place to fit both the text and the chart. You will probably have to reconsider layout on narrow viewports. It is unclear what your layout strategy is, so you might want to update your question with more information on the desired layout (a sketch or something will be extremely helpful).